# open graph - posting message with mention tagging

Tags: facebook-opengraph, tagging

```
if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("message", message);
  mAsyncRunner.request(uid + "/feed", parameters, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(h), null);
}

    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("profile", message);
  mAsyncRunner.request(uid + "/revill_:Tags", parameters, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(h), null);
}
```

i want to mention my frinends name on my news feed.

i Referenced this page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/mention-tagging/

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of doing this right now.

I found this page more helpful:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/people_tagging/

Make sure you're user is logged into your app as you'll need a session token

Here is more info about setting you app up for Open Graph integration:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/